# Mockito reset call count?

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

I am effectively calling a method of a mocked class 3 times in a test but when I assert that the call was method 3 times, the test fail. The actual call count is down to 1 according to the result from 2.
How does mockito counts calls ?

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
class RealService {
  doSomething(){

  }
}
class MockService extends Mock implements RealService{}
void main() {
  test('Mockito callcount 3 times',(){
    final mock = MockService();
    mock.doSomething();
    mock.doSomething();
    verify(mock.doSomething()).called(2);
    // now calling a third time again
    mock.doSomething();
    verify(mock.doSomething()).called(3);
  });
}
```

My background is from `sinon` in Node

```
Expected: <3>
  Actual: <1>
Unexpected number of calls
```

Comment: This is explained by the FAQ: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-can-a-method-call-not-be-verified-multiple-times

Answer (score 4):

Mockito has a [reset](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/reset.html) function that does exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

The `Mock` object maintains internally a list of `RealCall`. Each `RealCall` has a [`verified` flag](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/1dcd8225e9014b17ba256d7fa1d056f339189630/lib/src/mock.dart#L556).

For each verification, it only looks for un-verified call. And after the verification the flags are [set to true](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/1dcd8225e9014b17ba256d7fa1d056f339189630/lib/src/mock.dart#L684)

I did not find any documentation about this behaviour but the the code is available here: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/lib/src/mock.dart

Answer (score 1):

Use [clearInteractions](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/clearInteractions.html) to clear just the call count, [reset](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/reset.html) clears call count and stubs, so you'll need to restub.